# How to use mod_passenger for Turbogears 2?

Tags: python, passenger, turbogears, turbogears2

What do I put in passenger_wsgi.py for a Turbogears2 site?

Since it's possible for Django to use mod_passenger, I'm trying to use mod_passenger with Turbogears2.  So far, I've found a passenger_wsgi.py for Turbogears1, but I don't know where to start to make a passenger_wsgi.py for a Turbogears2 site.

Here's the Turbogears1 example: http://github.com/weyert/passenger-turbogears-example/blob/master/passenger_wsgi.py

Comment: Memory management on shared hosting.  I have many one-off projects that I don't need running all the time and passenger will automatically start the process when requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right question would be: how to write a WSGI file for Turbogears 2. If you have a WSGI file that works on other WSGI-compliant servers like mod_wsgi or Green Unicorn then it should work on Phusion Passenger as well.

Comment: Does this mean you are able to get it working on mod_wsgi but not on Phusion Passenger? What WSGI file did you end up using?